# Zend Session Fatal error

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I'm having following Zend Session error with my zend project:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /home/besthomes/public_html/Zend/Session.php(Line:426): Error #2 session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/besthomes/public_html/Zend/Exception.php:1) Array' in /home/besthomes/public_html/Zend/Session.php:432 Stack trace: #0 /home/besthomes/public_html/index.php(47): Zend_Session::start() #1 {main} thrown in /home/besthomes/public_html/Zend/Session.php on line 432
```

I have wrote this code in bootstrap file:

```
include('include.php');
include "Zend/Loader.php";

Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
Zend_Session::start();
```

i couldn't know the reason for this error. please help to get out of this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you don't have additional characters in your files. For example -
this code won't trigger an error:

```
<?php 
session_start();
```

but that one will:

```
(blank line here!)
<?php 
session_start();
```

Same thing applies to included files. But, when you include files you must also notice to do not have additional lines after clossing tag (if you use them). This will work:

```
<?php
    //content of included file
?>
```

but  something like that won't:

```
<?php
    //content of included file
?>    
(blank line here!)
(!and here)
```

So that's why some people consider [not using closing tag in php scripts](http://www.swiftlytilting.com/2010/10/14/dont-close-your-php-tags/) as good practice.

You can also workaround that problem using `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush`, but like I said - it's **workaround**, not **solution**.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your code, there is some output being done, which PHP will send the HTTP headers for. Since the HTTP headers are already sent, they cannot be sent again when trying to start the session. If you want to use sessions, starting the session early or first thing is a good idea.

On the other hand, I've seen this error when my app outputs a separate error, thus sending the HTTP headers.

Please have a look at the docs for further information:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.html

Namely the section called "Starting a Session": 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html

Tip:
Remove/comment out the lines that start the session, and see what is output. There may be another error, even unrelated to your code.

Comment: thanx but this error arise when some kind of malicious code was added in my bootstrap file, although i have removed that code but i don't know why this error coming as the same code was working perfectly before some days in bootstrap file.

Comment: i thought this can be related with cache?

Comment: Whitespace before opening php tag?

Comment: I would not really call it malicious code, unless a malicious person added it there to harm someone - like delete all the files on your hard disk or send out spam, etc. As I said, it is possible that another error is being output trigger this error, or as ArneRie says, maybe whitespace. I've added one more suggestion to my answer.

Comment: thank you very much for help, but one of my zend session file (framework package file) was affected by that code, i have removed that code from that file and now application running perfectly.

Comment: You should probably download ZF again. Don't edit ZF code - extend it.